# Cplex Optimization Studio: Stuck at 'Extract Configuration'

Tags: cplex

I have an assignment where I have to schedule talks based on participant preferences in time-blocks that can be scheduled in 3 parallel pathways. The goal is to obtain as much satisfaction (participants attending preferred talks) as possible. This takes some time since the 3 parallel pathways invoke symmetry (pathways are interchangeable without loss of satisfaction). When I try to break symmetry by setting a constraint that pathway 1 should hold the lowest indexed talk, pathway 2 second smallest and pathway 3 highest indexed talk, my profiler shows me that I am not able to complete the ‘extract – configuration’ phase. It works when keeping the input small but when called up, it seems it gets stuck here. I have added a printscreen of how it looks, when running longer it stays like this. When I delete the constraint everything works again (it only takes ages to complete due to the symmetry). Has anyone had this problem before or know how to solve it? I'm using Cplex Optimization studio Version: 12.10.0.0 .

Thank you in advance,

Ido

My code:

.mod

```
// ************* DATA

 int TotParallel=...; //Amount of possible parallel talks
 range Parallel=1..TotParallel;


{int} Talks=...; // Set of talks with int index
{int} Parts=...; // Set of particpants with int index
{int} Times=...; // Set of timeblocks with int index

int PREF[Parts][Talks]=...; // Preference of a part for certain talk

// for writing to excel
string writeConnectionEnroll="A1:D";
string writeConnectionSchedule="F1:I";


execute
{

writeConnectionEnroll+=Parts.size*Talks.size*Times.size;
writeConnectionSchedule+=Talks.size*Times.size*Parallel.size;
}



//************* Decision Variables

dvar boolean Enroll[Parts][Talks][Times]; // Enroll dv of participant for talk at timeslot
dvar boolean Schedule[Talks][Times][Parallel]; // Schedulling dv for talk at timeslot at parallel pathway


//************* Objective

maximize sum(p in Parts, x in Talks, t in Times) PREF[p][x]*Enroll[p][x][t];


// ************* Constraints
subject to{

    forall( p in Parts){
       sum(x in Talks)PREF[p][x] >= sum(t in Times, x in Talks)Enroll[p][x][t]; }
    // Participants only enroll in requested talks

    forall(p in Parts, x in Talks, t in Times){
       Enroll[p][x][t] <= sum(n in Parallel) Schedule[x][t][n];
      }
      // Participants can only be enrolled in scheduled sessions

    forall(x in Talks){
      sum(t in Times, n in Parallel) Schedule[x][t][n] ==1;
    }
    // Every talk scheduled at least once

    forall(x in Talks){
      forall(t in Times){
      sum(n in Parallel) Schedule[x][t][n] <=1;
    }
    // Every talk can be scheduled in at most 1 timeslot
       forall(t in Times, n in Parallel){
      sum(x in Talks) Schedule[x][t][n] <= 1;
    }
    // At most 1 talk per timeslot. 

    forall(p in Parts, t in Times){
      sum(x in Talks) Enroll[p][x][t] <= 1;
    }// Every participant can only be enrolled at max 1 talk at a time



     forall(t in Times){
     forall(p,q,r in Talks){
       forall(n in Parallel){
         ((Schedule[p][t][1]==1) && (Schedule[q][t][2]==1) && (Schedule[r][t][3] == 1)) => (p<q<r);
       }}}

    // Constraint to break symmetry: when 3 talks are scheduled in parallel, the talk with lowest index
    // is placed in pathway 1, second talk in pathway 2 and highest in pathway 3. When only 2 pathways are used nothing happens.
    /*
    forall(t in Times){
      forall(p,q,r in Talks:p<q<r){
        forall(m,n,o in Parallel){
          if((Schedule[p][t][m]==1) && (Schedule[q][t][n]==1) && (Schedule[r][t][o] == 1))  (m==1 && n==2 && o==3);
        }}}*/
    // Alternative constraint. Also doesn't work
    }}

     tuple xTuple{
       int a;
       int b;
       int c;
       int value;
     }

     {xTuple} EnrollT = {<p,x,t,Enroll[p][x][t]> | p in Parts, x in Talks, t in Times};
     {xTuple} ScheduleT = {<x,t,n,Schedule[x][t][n]> | x in Talks, t in Times, n in Parallel};

     // Tuple used to write to excel
```

.dat :

```
TotParallel=3;
Times= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24};
SheetConnection my_sheet("1sand0s.xlsx"); 
// Reading from Excel. It contains preferences of 100 participants for 70 talks. A 1 is given if the participant prefers certain talk, 0 otherwise.
Talks from SheetRead(my_sheet,"B1:BS1");// Komt overeen met deel dat 'Talks' heet in excel
Parts from SheetRead(my_sheet,"A2:A101");// Komt overeen met deel dat 'Parts' heet in excel
PREF from SheetRead(my_sheet,"B2:BS101");//  


SheetConnection sheet("Solutions2.xlsx");
EnrollT to SheetWrite(sheet,writeConnectionEnroll);
ScheduleT to SheetWrite(sheet,writeConnectionSchedule);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaUNV.png)

Comment: Hi, why not sharing your code in your post so that other users could help ?

Comment: Yes excuse me, I have added it

Comment: Could you add some concrete data? Looking at your constraint, there are going to be *a lot* of individual constraints being generated: You will have `|Times| x |Talks|^3 x |Parallel|^3` individual constraints. Maybe it just takes a very long time to generate those? What is the dimension of Times, Talks, and Parallel?

Comment: Perhaps that is it. The input data is an excel dataframe consisting of 70 talks (columns) and 100 participants (rows). Each cell contains a 1 or 0 depending on the preference of the participant for that talk. The model will have to schedule these talks in such a way that overall preference is maximized. The talks can be scheduled in 3 parallel paths for 24 timeblocks (so in total 72 spots for 70 talks).